# Как добавить страницу в Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть стартовая страница авторизации с использованием Devise, нужно настроить редирект на HTML страницу. Приложение развернуто на локальном сервере. Как именно это сделать? Буду благодарен любой помощи и информации, так как новичок в Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятны условия вопроса.

Если вам нужно изменить стартовую страницу, воспользуйтесь `root to: 'examples#main'` в маршрутах.

Если вам нужен редирект после успешного входа, используйте `redirect_to some_url` в вашем контроллере.

Больше информации [Здесь](http://rusrails.ru/rails-routing) и [Здесь](http://rusrails.ru/layouts-and-rendering-in-rails)